# Formatar o retorno da função Now() do MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sqlfiddle

Então pessoal.

Preciso saber se a algum jeito de enviar somente as horas H:i:s da função `NOW()` no banco de dados, ou enviar o `NOW()` completo e depois buscar **somente** as horas?

Comment: Você quer obter ou salvar a hora?

Comment: Ambos. Preciso da hora **exata** do dispositivo do usuário entrando no brasil ou japão e salvar no banco de dados.

Comment: Qual o tipo do campo? date? timestamp?

Comment: date, mas aque vc achar melhor de trabalhar pode dizer @rray , mas tem que ser a hora exata.. de onde a pessoa estiver acessando.. tem como buscar isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer o insert apenas com a função `now()` lembra que para utilizar a hora é necessário que campo seja `datetime` ou `timestamp`, para exibir os resultados formatados use a função date [date_format()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) do mysql, use as funções [hour](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour), [minute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_minute) ou [second](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_second) para fazer comparações.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%H:%i:%s')

//exemplo do sqlfiddle
SELECT id, date_format(data,'%H:%i:%s') FROM datas WHERE hour(data) = 14
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a55d/4)

Answer (score 4):

Tente formatando o valor da saída, exemplo: 
`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%H:%i:%s');`