# Omitir segundos no campo time MySQL

Tags: mysql

Galera tenho um campo em minha tabela do tipo `time`, onde eu salvo minha hora. O problema é que ele está salvando assim: `10:30:01`, como faço para ele salvar apenas a hora e os minutos. Ou seja sem os segundos?

O campo esta assim no BD `hora time DEFAULT NULL`

Comment: Qual o problema? se quer descartar os segundos use a formatação(`date_format()`)

Comment: como faço para ela formatar a hora sem os segundos?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74425/91

Comment: Como você está inserindo os valores nesse campo?

Comment: Salvo no padrão time, H:i:s

Comment: Como vc está salvando sua data hoje?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assim como [rray](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/91/rray) disse, você tem as seguintes opções [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) e [`TIME_FORMAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format):

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%H:%i");

TIME_FORMAT(NOW(), "%H:%i");
```

Acredito que para teu caso, o `TIME_FORMAT` seja mais indicado:

```
SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(hora_entrega, "%H:%i") as hora_entrega FROM pedidos
```

Comment: `time_format` parece mais adequado :) +1

Comment: entendo, como falei no comentario, tenho que aplicar isso a um select onde leio todos os campos da tabela. Como fazer isso?

Comment: `SELECT *, TIME_FORMAT(hora_entrega,  "%H:%i") as hora_entrega FROM pedidos`

Answer (score 8):

Pode fazer as comparações e apresentações da hora usando a função `date_format()` do MySQL para suprimir os segundos. `H` representa a hora no formato 0-23 e `i` os minutos. Mesmo que os segundos sejam omitidos no insert o campo fica gravado com `00` segundos.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT date_format('%H:%i', now())
```

[Lista de argumentos aceito por date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: corrige a ordem dos parâmetros, `DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`, conforme a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: OK, porém faço o seguinte select: `select * from pedidos` onde preciso ler todos os campos ta tabela pedido, e la dentre tenho 2 campos time,`hora_entrega` e `hora_pedido`. Com aplico esta formatação?

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade valeu :D, corrigido.

Comment: @HugoBorges precisa especificar essa formatação para esses dois campos, `SELECT *, date_format(hora_entreta, '%H:%i') as hora_entrega, date_format(hora_pedido, '%H:%i') as hora_pedido FROM pedidos`